# How do I modify this code to use another project in the solution

Tags: dll

```
        public void Launch()
    {
        if (LinkedInstance != null) return;
        LinkedInstance = new OrderInstance(ServiceLocation, Algorithm, MaxPrice, Limit, PoolData, ID, StartingPrice, StartingAmount);

        if (HandlerDLL.Length > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                Assembly ASS = Assembly.LoadFrom(HandlerDLL);
                Type T = ASS.GetType("HandlerClass");
                HandlerMethod = T.GetMethod("HandleOrder");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

This code will open an assembly based on file name and assign HandlerMethod with T.GetMethod.

The thing is I do not want to create a dll file.

I want to do this with a project file in the solution.

The type of HandlerMethod is this

```
    private MethodInfo HandlerMethod;
```

So How do I assign HandlerMethod to point to a method in a class I have.

It just happens that the name of the assembly of sample Handler is Handler Example

So I tried to change the code to this

```
                Assembly ASS = Assembly.LoadFrom("HandlerExample");
                Type T = ASS.GetType("HandlerClass");
                HandlerMethod = T.GetMethod("HandleOrder");
```

It simply cause exception.

How do I arrange that ASS would refer to the dll file that is in another project in the solution. I want minimal code change.

Comment: Why not add reference to that project? and "I do not want to create a dll file" is confusing, because if the other project is a class library, then the dll file will definitely be created.

Comment: And if the class is in the same project, you can use Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

Answer (score 1):

If the method is present in some other project then you can either add a reference to that project and use the method directly, or if you want to use reflection, then `Assembly ASS = Assembly.LoadFrom(HandlerDLL);` will do the job that you are already using.

If the class is in the same project then you can use `Assembly ASS = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();` and in this case you don't need to provide dll name.

*Note: Though it is not mentioned by OP what language he is using, but the code looks like c# to me.*

Comment: what should I fill handlerdll with? The class is in a different project in an assembly

Comment: HandlerDLL should be a string containing the full path to the dll file.

Comment: what about if I do not want to use a dll file I want to use another project in the solution

Comment: how exactly should I use the method directly?

Comment: You can use add reference dialog to add a reference to that projects under 'Projects' tab. Then you can create instance of the class and access the method, or if it is a static method, you can use Class.Method directly.

Comment: I want minimal code change. Basically I want variable ASS to contain an assembly on the other object.

Comment: In that case just assign the dll file path to HandlerDLL variable.